# Swift Socket IO: Closing socket does not stop reconnect attempts

Tags: swift, socket.io

I was doing some code refactoring today and I noticed that closing the socket in socket IO does not stop the reconnect attempts. The only solution that comes to mind was to set the socketManager.reconnects to false when closing the socket and to set it back to true when I am connecting again but I encountered an issue here as well.

When I close the socket and set the reconnects to false, reconnection attempts stop as expected, but then I set it to true and try connecting and there is only 1 connection attempt is being made and it does not try to reconnect again. I checked the socket manager. reconnects value and it is indeed set to true but the reconnection attempt does not occur.

Am I doing something wrong here or is it a bug in the library. Here is my code.

```
let socketManager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: Constants.serverSocketURL)!, config: [.log(true), .reconnects(true), .reconnectAttempts(500), .reconnectWait(1)])

lazy var socket = socketManager.defaultSocket

func establishConnection() {
    socketManager.reconnects = true
    if !self.isConnected() {
        print(self.socketManager.reconnects)
        socket.connect(timeoutAfter: 7.0) {
            Logger.log(message: "Socket connection timeout", event: .i)
        }
    }
}

func closeConnection() {
    turnOffListeners()
    socket.disconnect()
    socketManager.reconnects = false
}
```

Comment: Which queue are you running this on ? can you try using the main queue ? , I.E. `DispatchQueue.main` ? sounds like a race condition to me

Comment: Huh, interesting idea. When you say it might be a race condition, are you talking about the fact that disconnect does not stop the reconnect attempts or that setting reconnects = true have no effect? '

Comment: Yeah it could be any of those it’s hard to tell without seeing more code, might be also the fact that every new connection instantiates a new copy of the manager, causing multiple instances to live around, easiest is to test and see to rule out if this is the case

Comment: Mostafa I tried running the socketManager.reconnects change and connection and disconnection in DispatchQueue.main.sync but it made no difference. Trying to connect after disconnect call still only makes one reconnect attempt.

Comment: Please check   https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/442

Comment: Noman I tried that method but as I mentioned in my post, after forcing .reconnects to false and then set it to true before connecting breaks the connection reconnect and only one attempt is being made.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing more of your code it will be hard to find the actual problem. What I can do right now is to show you my implementation of Socket.io in Swift. Maybe this will help you.

**SocketHelper.swift**

```
class SocketHelper: NSObject {

    static let shared = SocketHelper()

    private let manager = SocketManager(
        socketURL: URL(string: ApiConstants.Routes.URL)!,
        config: [.forceNew(true)]
    )

    private var socket: SocketIOClient!

    var isConnected: Bool = false

    private override init() {
        super.init()

        socket = manager.defaultSocket

        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect, callback: { data, ack in
            print("SocketManager: connected")
            self.isConnected = true
            self.sendNotification(event: "CONNECTED")
        })

        socket.on(clientEvent: .disconnect, callback: { data, ack in
            print("SocketManager: disconnected")
            self.isConnected = false
            self.sendNotification(event: "DISCONNECTED")
        })
    }

    private func sendNotification(event: String) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(event), object: nil)
    }

    func connect() {
        if !isConnected {
            socket.connect()
        }
    }

    func disconnect() {
        if isConnected {
            socket.disconnect()
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside a ViewController you should register Observers:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(socketConnected), name: NSNotification.Name("CONNECTED"), object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(socketDisconnected), name: NSNotification.Name("DISCONNECTED"), object: nil)
```

Connect to socket:

```
SocketHelper.shared.connect()
```

Wait for the event:

```
@objc func socketConnected() {
    //connected
}

@objc func socketDisconnected() {
    //disconnected
}
```

Comment: Kai I pretty much do the same thing in my code. THe only difference is that I use these configs for socket manager

config: [.log(false), .reconnects(true), .reconnectAttempts(500), .reconnectWait(1)]

Answer (score 0):

This one works great for me, though , its shoots one more attempt before stops completely.

socket.io-client": "2.2.0"

`this.socket.io.reconnectionAttempts(0);`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it